# Select one per unique ID with newest timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in Big Query with unique IDs , timestamps and distances and would like to select one record by ID with the newest timestamp.

E.g. the table looks like

```
ID|timestamp|distance
A|100|2
A|90|3
B|110|5
D|100|4
A|80|2
B|10|2
```

The query should return something like:

```
A|100|2
B|110|5
D|100|4
```

A working query in PostgreSQL looks like this, but there is no "distinct ON" in bigquery?

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ID)
id, timestamp, distance
FROM ranking
ORDER BY ID, timestamp DESC
) AS latest_dtg
ORDER BY distance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this one?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM yourtable AS a
INNER JOIN (
SELECT id, MAX(timestamp) AS newesttimestamp
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id
) AS b 
ON a.id = b.id AND a.timestamp = b.newesttimestamp
ORDER BY a.id
```

Answer (score 5):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT row.* FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(r ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS row
  FROM ranking AS r
  GROUP BY id
)
```

You can play/test with below dummy data from your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH ranking AS (
  SELECT 'A' AS id, 100 AS timestamp, 2 AS distance UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 90, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 110, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D', 100, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 10, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 80, 2
)
SELECT row.* FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(r ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS row
  FROM ranking AS r
  GROUP BY id
)
```

Comment: this is a terrific answer, I was trying to accomplish the same task

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea:

```
#standardSQL
WITH ranking AS
(SELECT 'A' id, 100 ts, 2 distance UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 90, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 110, 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 100, 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 10, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 80, 2)
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(ts, distance) ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)]
FROM ranking
GROUP BY id
```