# Select the last user_property in a dataset in bigQuery per user

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this query, and the goal of it is to get all the user_properties of the events that are stored in the dataset, now the result is around 300k+ per day and it is quite too big and I only care for one user_property per user since it will have the keys that I want

To explain it more, we record the events done by a user on the mobile/web app in the dataset, so each button he clicks or every screen he searches for, we record those in order to be used later for analysis by clients, so a single user may have 0 or 100 events per day or more and usually, the last event been recorded contains all the updated keys I want

```
SELECT
   user_pseudo_id AS user_id,
   user_properties AS user_properties
FROM
   `TABLENAME`
order by user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp
```

I tried grouping the user_properties by user_pseaudo_id, but that obviously didn't work because the properties are not the same
My solution was to get all the results from the query above, loop over the result, and store them in a `Map<String, List<FieldValue>>`, well this solution Is doing the trick but `userPropertiesResult.iterateAll()` is too expensive and is taking a lot of time

So I came up with a better query that reduced the number of rows by a lot following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43863450/7298897

```
SELECT
  a.user_pseudo_id AS user_id,
  a.user_properties AS user_properties
FROM
  `TABLENAME` AS a
JOIN (
  SELECT
    user_pseudo_id,
    MAX(event_timestamp) AS event_timestamp
  FROM
    `TABLENAME`
  GROUP BY
    user_pseudo_id) AS b
ON
  a.user_pseudo_id = b.user_pseudo_id
  AND a.event_timestamp = b.event_timestamp
```

But the problem is that the data returned is not accurate as it was before

So my question would be, How I can get the last user_property only per user?

Comment: I don't see a reason why the results from the posted query would be inaccurate. Is there something we don't know about the data? What's the structure of the user_properties? I think there is some work that could be done with it.

Comment: The way I was doing it before updating the query is that I get all the user_properties sorted by user_id and event_timestamp to make sure to get all the user_props for a user by time order, and then I put them in a map in Java and with user_id as key, so after iterating over all the user_properies, I'm sure that I have a map of user_id as a key and the last event done by that user as the value.
I was testing for a particular day, in the old way the size of the map (number of unique users was around 6.6k) meanwhile with the new query, the number of unique users was around 6.2k for the same day